# static casting for systemverilog

Tags: casting, static, system-verilog

I try to use static cast in systemverilog code.
I have variable of type logic:

```
logic [127:0] data[];
```

and I want to obtain variable of type bit. For this, I wrote the following code:

```
bit [127:0] bit_data [];
bit [127:0] b_data; 

typedef bit [127:0] bit_127_t;
bit_data = bit_127_t' (data);
b_data = bit_data[0];
```

this code didn't work.. and I don't find the error. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say something doesn't work, it always help to show what's not working about it. Like did you  get a different result than expected, or a compiler error?

I think your `typedef` is incorrect. It should be

```
typedef bit [127:0] bit_127_t[];
```

It would also help to use the same typedef in the declaration of bit_data.

Comment: I have a question... Can I use dynamic casting in this case too?

Comment: No, $cast does not do any data manipulation. It's only use is for class handles.